# Facing an error when loading a pretrained tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have trained a tensorflow model to be used in another model. when I load a keras pretrained model using `xception = keras.applications.Xception( include_top=False, weights="imagenet", pooling="avg" )` then my below code works fine.

```
def create_vision_encoder(
num_projection_layers, projection_dims, dropout_rate, trainable=False
):
# Load the pre-trained Xception model to be used as the base encoder.
xception = keras.applications.Xception(
    include_top=False, weights="imagenet", pooling="avg"
)

# Set the trainability of the base encoder.
for layer in xception.layers:
    layer.trainable = trainable
# Receive the images as inputs.
inputs = layers.Input(shape=(299, 299, 3), name="image_input")

BATCH_SIZE = 1
NUM_BOXES = 5
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 256
IMAGE_WIDTH = 256
CHANNELS = 3
CROP_SIZE = (24, 24)

#image = tf.random.normal(shape=(BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH,
#CHANNELS) )
boxes = tf.random.uniform(shape=(NUM_BOXES, 4))
box_indices = tf.random.uniform(shape=(NUM_BOXES,), minval=0,
maxval=BATCH_SIZE, dtype=tf.int32)
output = tf.image.crop_and_resize(inputs, boxes, box_indices, CROP_SIZE)

# Preprocess the input image.
xception_input = tf.keras.applications.xception.preprocess_input(output)
# Generate the embeddings for the images using the xception model.
embeddings = xception(xception_input)
# Project the embeddings produced by the model.
outputs = project_embeddings(
    embeddings, num_projection_layers, projection_dims, dropout_rate
)
# Create the vision encoder model.
return keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name="vision_encoder")
```

However when I use my pretrained model `xception = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/MLC')` in the above code like this

```
def create_vision_encoder(
num_projection_layers, projection_dims, dropout_rate, trainable=False
):
# Load the pre-trained Xception model to be used as the base encoder.
xception = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/MLC')

# Set the trainability of the base encoder.
for layer in xception.layers:
    layer.trainable = trainable
# Receive the images as inputs.
inputs = layers.Input(shape=(299, 299, 3), name="image_input")

BATCH_SIZE = 1
NUM_BOXES = 5
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 256
IMAGE_WIDTH = 256
CHANNELS = 3
CROP_SIZE = (24, 24)

#image = tf.random.normal(shape=(BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH,
#CHANNELS) )
boxes = tf.random.uniform(shape=(NUM_BOXES, 4))
box_indices = tf.random.uniform(shape=(NUM_BOXES,), minval=0,
maxval=BATCH_SIZE, dtype=tf.int32)
output = tf.image.crop_and_resize(inputs, boxes, box_indices, CROP_SIZE)

# Preprocess the input image.
xception_input = tf.keras.applications.xception.preprocess_input(output)
# Generate the embeddings for the images using the xception model.
embeddings = xception(xception_input)
# Project the embeddings produced by the model.
outputs = project_embeddings(
    embeddings, num_projection_layers, projection_dims, dropout_rate
)
# Create the vision encoder model.
return keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name="vision_encoder")
```

Then it generates this error

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "max_pooling2d_1" (type MaxPooling2D).

Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 2 for '{{node sequential/max_pooling2d_1/MaxPool}} = MaxPool[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", explicit_paddings=[], ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1]](sequential/batch_normalization_1/FusedBatchNormV3)' with input shapes: [5,2,2,256].

Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(5, 2, 2, 256), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: When you are saving the model are you sure you are ONLY saving the `xception` module and not the whole vision encoder model?.

Comment: I have trained alexnet but named xception here. The code of alexnet pretrained model is in this colab [FILE](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18ZGqO6dfjgTS6QWuf0eueqTFHb6ab236?usp=sharing). I saved it in drive and now I am loading it in vision encoder but it generates this error.